# Interesting Proofs using degree theory technique

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Many times I faced proofs using degree theory technique and I am interested in such proofs and I want to know more about powerfulness of  this technique and see more proofs using this technique. I would be appreciate if you show me your experience about this.